# Copy only files that have similar names

Tags: command-line, bash

My bash-fu is not up to the task. Could you assist me please? 
I have a folder that contains:

```
viper.jpg
marshmallow.jpg
spider.jpg
cockroach.jpg
muffin.jpg
taffy.jpg
```

And a folder that contains

```
viper.doc
spider.doc
cockroach.doc
```

I need to copy from folder 1 to folder 2 only relevant illustrations, for which filenames match. How?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/q/291086/295286 Short answer: use a for loop on folder1 with prefix removal on each file

Comment: @KonradGajewski So? Nearly nothing is really Ubuntu specific. This question is on topic here!

Comment: There's actually a great post 
as to whether general scripting is on topic on this site.  https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/13807/295286  Be it my will, Python scripting would remain here as well, since it's 2018 and there's whole lot of scripting tasks that bash just can't handle. But that's just a side note. Scripting is on topic.

Comment: And file copying/processing isn't required to be Ubuntu-specific anyway, since these are general tasks that all operating systems should be capable of doing, including Ubuntu. The only thing that truly should be Ubuntu specific here is the answers. If someone comes here saying "This doesn't work on Mac",  it doesn't matter because ot doesn't have to work on Mac -  answers here have to be Ubuntu specific

Answer (score 4):

Very simple with [bash parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe):

```
#!/bin/bash
cd folder2
for i in *; do
    cp "../folder1/${i%.*}.jpg" .
done
```

Handles spaces, newlines, and whatever other weird characters you throw at it.

Also, if you have more file types than .jpg that you want to copy, you can replace the `cp` command above with this one (note the final `*` goes outside the quotes):

```
    cp "../folder1/${i%.*}."* .
```

If you have files with multiple extensions (such as `.tar.gz`) and you want to strip them all, change the `%` to `%%`.

Comment: Call `cp` for every single file? We can do better than that, how about filling an array like `for i in *; do files+=( ${i%.*}.jpg ); done` and calling `cp` just once on the array with `cp "/path/to/folder1/${files[@]}" .` – or, if `Argument list too long`, as often as necessary with: `printf "%s\0" "/path/to/folder1/${files[@]}" | xargs -0 cp -t`

Comment: @dessert True, but there's definitely a tradeoff between performance and complexity to be made.

Answer (score 2):

With `find` and [shell (POSIX sh/bash/Korn/zsh) parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

```
find /absolute/path/to/dIR2 -type f -name '*.doc' -execdir sh -c '
    echo cp /absolute/path/to/dIR1/${0%.doc}.jpg .
' {} \;

cp /absolute/path/to/dIR1/./cockroach.jpg .
cp /absolute/path/to/dIR1/./spider.jpg .
cp /absolute/path/to/dIR1/./viper.jpg .
```

Where:

```
.
├── dIR1
│   ├── cockroach.jpg
│   ├── marshmallow.jpg
│   ├── muffin.jpg
│   ├── spider.jpg
│   ├── taffy.jpg
│   └── viper.jpg
└── dIR2
    ├── cockroach.doc
    ├── spider.doc
    └── viper.doc
```

result (remove `echo` in front of the `cp` to perform copy on files):

```
.
├── dIR1
│   ├── cockroach.jpg
│   ├── marshmallow.jpg
│   ├── muffin.jpg
│   ├── spider.jpg
│   ├── taffy.jpg
│   └── viper.jpg
└── dIR2
    ├── cockroach.doc
    ├── cockroach.jpg
    ├── spider.doc
    ├── spider.jpg
    ├── viper.doc
    └── viper.jpg
```

To prevent calling `cp` for every files found, we can use the command as following way:

```
find /absolute/path/to/dIR2 -type f -name '*.doc' -execdir bash -c '
    printf "/absolute/path/to/dIR1/%s.jpg\0" "$'{@%.doc}'"' _ {} + \
    | xargs -0 cp -t /absolute/path/to/dIR2
```

Comment: Would the `/./` in file path be any problem though ? Referring to output in the first codeblock

Comment: no, please check this post https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/249041/72456 _`/a/./ -> still in /a`_

Comment: Very well, thanks. Already upvoted both posts.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fun one:

```
find ./f1 -type f -exec sh -c 'bn=$(basename -s ".jpg" "$1");test -f "$2"/"$bn".doc || exit 1' sh  {} ./f2 \; -and -exec echo cp {} ./f2 \;
```

Or with indentation as a script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

find "$1" -type f -exec sh -c '
        bn=$(basename -s ".jpg" "$1");
        test -f "$2"/"$bn".doc || exit 1' sh  {} "$2" \; \
    -and -exec echo cp {} "$2" \;
```

Confused yet ? It's actually very simple:

- `find` will traverse the directory given by `$1` variable and look only for items of type f, that is "regular file".
- for each file we have two `-exec` calls, joined with `-and` flag, which will will execute the second `-exec` only if first succeeds, kinda like `&&` does in shell scripts.
- First `exec` performs the function and extracting the basename of a file with stripping of `.jpeg` extension, which is all done within an instance of `/bin/sh` called with `-c` flag. Shells called with `-c` flag place the first positional parameter into variable `$0`, which is why the first positional parameter has to be `sh`. After that `{}` is the file currently processed, and `"$2` will be the directory where you want to check the duplicates, that is `folder 2` from OP example.
- `bn=$(basename -s ".jpg" "$1")` extracts base and strips the extension from currently processed file, thus if we have `./f1/foo.jpg` being processed, the result is `foo` saved in `bn` variable. `test -f "$2"/"$bn".doc || exit 1` will check if same basename but with .doc extension exists in target directory, and if not - will return exit status of 1, which prevents the second `-exec` being run by `find`.
- if after all the shell exits normally with exit status 0, this means filename exists in target directory, and we can run second `-exec` which is `echo cp {} ./f2 \;`  **NOTE**: remove `echo` part for actual copying to take place, `echo` prior to `cp` is for testing only so that you can make sure you copy only things that need to be copied and is generally the good practice.

So, with a directory structure as so:

```
$ tree
.
├── dir 1
│   ├── bar.jpg
│   └── foo.jpg
├── findbasenames.sh
└── top dir
    └── dir 2
        └── foo.doc
```

You can see there's `foo.jpg` and `foo.doc`.  Running the script we get:

```
$ ./findbasenames.sh  'dir 1'/ ./top\ dir/dir\ 2/
cp dir 1/foo.jpg dir 1/
```

As you can see, the script deals with directories that contain spaces in their name, multiple levels of directories (so you don't need to `cd` anywhere), and `find` is recursive, if you ever need that to find duplicate basenames in multiple directories, although with `-maxdepth 1` flag you can tell `find` to work through only files in current directory.  Plus this should handle difficult filenames, such as `-foo.doc`. This might be a lengthy and roundabout way, but can be fairly flexible.

Comment: Wouldn’t `-exec echo cp -t "$2" {} +` be better, calling `cp` only as often as necessary?

Comment: @dessert  Yes, if we were could verify all files in bulk exist via first `-exec`.  We can resort to doing something like `-exec sh -c 'for f; do ... done;' sh {} +` but it makes no sense, unless for some reason we only have `sh` available but need recursion.

Comment: @dessert I think if you do want to bump up performance for such task, you could do something with `parallel`. This task is by nature is linear, so code can only go this far, but if you can parallelize linear tasks, that's gonna be better.

Answer (score 1):

This has a few nice features:

- Handles subdirectories (*e*.*g*., `src/a/b/c/d/e.jpg` is copied to `dst/a/b/c/d/e.jpg` when `dst/a/b/c/d/e.doc` exists)
- Shows what it's copying as it goes
- Uses filename suffixes rather than file extensions to handle dots in filenames perfectly regardless of how many dots are in the filename or the desired suffix
- The directories and suffixes aren't hardcoded in the script, so it's much easier to reuse the script for other purposes
- Handles all characters properly, including all whitespace and all glob and regex metacharacters
- Running the script with no arguments gives a short usage example based on this question

It's been simplified greatly with the help of Joseph Sible's "[bash parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe)" link and the idea to use a shell script in `find -exec` from the answers of αғsнιη and Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

[ "$#" -ne "4" ] && printf 'Usage:   "%s" [source-directory] [source-file-suffix] [destination-directory] [destination-file-suffix]\nExample: "%s" pictures .jpg documents .doc\n' "$0" "$0" && exit 1
[ ! -d "$1" ] && echo '"'"$1"'" is not a directory!' && exit 2
[ ! -d "$3" ] && echo '"'"$3"'" is not a directory!' && exit 3

export srcdir="$1" srcsuf="$2" dstdir="$3" dstsuf="$4" dstsufglob="$( sed 's/./\\&/g' <<< "$4" )"
# Turn off fnmatch(3)'s strange options so that find(1)'s `-name` argument works normally
unset FNM_NOESCAPE FNM_PATHNAME FNM_PERIOD FNM_FILE_NAME FNM_LEADING_DIR FNM_CASEFOLD
find "$dstdir" -type f -name '*'"$dstsufglob" -exec bash -c '
  dst="{}"
  dst="${dst%$dstsuf}$srcsuf"
  src="${dst#$dstdir}"
  src="$srcdir/${src#/}"
  [ -f "$src" ] && cp -v "$src" "$dst"
' \;
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for a loop, good old globbing.

```
# assuming we are directory above folder{1,2}
# also assume no spaces in file names
# real file names don't have spaces :p

cd folder2
F=$(echo * | sed -e 's/\.doc/\.\*/g')
cd ../folder1 && cp $F ../folder2
```

Comment: What if there are whitespaces?

Comment: Whitespace is handled by line 3 ;-). I thought it was obvious that my goal was a one-liner that I might use for a one-off from the command-line, not a reusable script with all the bells and whistles for shaving a yak. Also, as the very first commenter pointed out: that was already done in [another question](https://askubuntu.com/q/291086/295286).